# Matching words in ANSI C

Tags: c, match, matching, cpu-word, ansi-c

How can I match a word (1-n characters) in ANSI C? (in addition: What is the pattern to match a constant in C-sourcecode?)

I tried reading the file and passing it to `regexec()` (regex.h).
Problem: The tool I'm writing should be able to read sourcecode and find
all used constants (#define) to check if they're defined.

The pattern used for testing is: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]{1,}`. But this would match words such as the "h" in "test.h".

Comment: What do you mean by a "word"? Is "jkasdf" a word? What about "42"?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8368681/968261) should help.

Comment: As I said: Words = preprocessor constant

Comment: Sorry, the question linked doesn't help since a constant could be used in any context like: (FOO), {FOO}, %%FOO%% and also \tFOO

Comment: Why don't you use the preprocessor for this? For your compiler this might be different but e.g gcc gives you the preprocessed source code with `-E` (so your defines are replaced) and there are also options to have him spit out all macros that are defined. (I don't think that `regexp.h` is part of C).

Comment: Do your portion of thinking and it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers must start with a letter or underscore, so the pattern is

```
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*
```

I know of no syntactic difference between C and preprocessor identifiers. There is a convention to use upper case for preprocessor and lowercase for C identifiers, but no actual requirement. Unless defines are guaranteed to use a distinct naming convention you would basically have to find every identifier in the source file and any included files and sort them into preprocessor identifiers, C identifiers and undeclared identifiers.

From the GCC manual:

> Preprocessing tokens fall into five broad classes: identifiers, preprocessing numbers, string literals, punctuators, and other. An identifier is the same as an identifier in C: any sequence of letters, digits, or underscores, which begins with a letter or underscore. Keywords of C have no significance to the preprocessor; they are ordinary identifiers. You can define a macro whose name is a keyword, for instance. The only identifier which can be considered a preprocessing keyword is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides doing regex searches over C source code would be to use a preprocessor library like [Boost Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/wave/index.html) or perhaps something like [Coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Absolutely agree with that but I didn't find a library fitting my needs. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Lexer grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) and the [Parser grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) (in flex and bison format, respectively) for the entire c language.  In particular, the part relevant to identifiers is:

```
D           [0-9]
L           [a-zA-Z_]
{L}({L}|{D})*       { count(); return(check_type()); }
```

So the id can start with any uppercase or lowercase letter or an underscore, and then have more uppercase or lowercase letters, underscores, and numbers. I believe it doesn't match parts of file names because they're quoted and it handles quotes separately.